# How to find the gps in the android device is correctly working or not?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-2.2-froyo, samsung-mobile

I'm developing an **android application for mobiles and tablets.**

I'm using android **version 2.2 , API 8.**

In my application, I want to capture the location co-ordinates via gps and send to server.

It's working fine .

When I working in my office (near to my office) the gps - co-ordinates captured correctly in android devices

But in only one device the co-ordinates captured wrongly. I'm in **Alwarpet,chennai,india** .But, I run that device it shows "**Andra pradesh" or bay of "bengal**".But all other device shows correct location.

I think there is a fault in device. But I'm not sure.

**How to find the gps in the android device is correctly working or not?**

All are welcome to give their ideas.

For testing I'm using Samsung devices such as Galaxy pop,Galaxy Fit,etc.

I'm tested in 3 Galaxy pop its working correctly.

I'm also tested in 2 galaxy fit device.One device works correctly but other device its shows wrong co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.
 
Google gives defaultly some application in android mobiles which uses google maps,gps,etc
 
The following are the application names

- Latitude
- Navigation

If we run any 1 of the above application.If it shows correct location then gps working in the mobile is fine.Otherwise it have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

as Said by @npinti :

The problem with GPS is that it is highly dependent on your whereabouts. Things such as tall buildings and sometimes even large trees can have a major impact on your GPS readings. Being inside a structure or outside is also another major factor which must be considered. Also, most of the time, the GPS will return different GPS co-ordinates even if you stay in the same place.

The average margin of error of a GPS usually varies between 5 and 50m. When you say 'forward' and 'backward' location, I am assuming that you mean that the GPS is returning a value for a position which is either ahead of you or behind you.

The fact that, as you say, the GPS most of the time works, leads me to suspect that the issue you are experiencing varies depending on your actual physical location, however, due to the vague nature of your question we can only speculate...

My suggestion is that you try this out in various places, maybe some with clear access to the sky, and another in a crowded area and you see how the GPS behaves.