# NETWORK_PROVIDER not giving callback to onLocationChanged()

Tags: android, networking, provider

I'm developing an application in which I fetch user location using NETWORK_PROVIDER it works fine on almost all devices but on KARBONN A15 onLocationChanged() is never called when we use NETWORK_PROVIDER but if we enable or disable the Network Provider in settings onProviderEnabled() and onProviderDisabled() are getting called this rules out the possibility that probably location listener is not getting attached properly also if I use GPS_PROVIDER instead of NETWORK_PROVIDER than onLocationChanged is getting called perfectly.

Below is code snippet :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10*1000, 0, this);
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("LocationDemo", "onLocationChanged() called with " + location.toString());

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.i("LocationDemo", "onProviderDisabled() called with " + provider);

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.i("LocationDemo", "onProviderEnabled() called with " + provider);

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.i("LocationDemo", "onStatusChanged() called with " + provider);

}
```

Thanks for your support I'm already in touch with Karbonn over this.
Is there anything I can do to check what's wrong with the device it would helpful if I'm able to identify the issue.

I've googled about the issue and found that there's a NetworkLocationService which is possibly doing the Location lookup for Network Provider but I don't know the way I can check if it's hitting the right Google Location Server's URL or not or what's the response from the servers in case it's getting.

I tried to inspect the log and there's something which I think might be the root of problem.

Below is the log :

> ```
>   01-02 19:17:06.790: I/ONCRPC(109): oncrpc_proxy_handle_cmd_rpc_call: Dispatching xid: 6b6
>    01-02 19:17:06.790: I/ONCRPC(109): oncrpc_xdr_reply_msg_start: Prog: 00000000, Ver: 00000000, Proc: 00000000 Xid: 000006b6
>    01-02 19:17:06.790: I/ONCRPC(109): oncrpc_msg_reply: Prog: 00000000, Ver: 00000000, Proc: 00000000 Xid: 000006b6
>    01-02 19:17:06.790: I/ONCRPC(109): oncrpc_proxy_handle_cmd_rpc_call: Dispatch returned for xid: 6b6
> ```

Comment: <br>Go to link 
[How to find the gps in the android device is correctly working or not?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12889583/385138

then you get an idea

Comment: try locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); with different simcards